# Ошибка при многократном нажатии на кнопку

Tags: spring, html, java

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема.. при быстром многоразовом нажатии на кнопку на htlm страничке выскакивает ошибка.

> NestedServletException: Request processing failed.

Используется spring mvc + freemarker. Вероятно, каждый поток запроса обращается к одному ресурсу, и все валится. Как заблокировать кнопку от момента нажатия на неё до того момента, когда страница перезагрузится?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так, как водится, проблему "двойного списания" решают на обеих концах. Во-первых, решите проблему, которая у вас на сервере: почему, собственно, у вас нет повтороной входимости? Во-вторых, используйте на клиентской стороне JavaScript чтобы заблокировать кнопку.

Comment: Может есть пример скрипта? Я как-то не силён в этом вопросе... думаю блокировкой кнопки этот вопрос решится, т.к. дописывать синхронизацию потоков не очень хочется...

Comment: Вид этого скрипта зависит от того, как выглядит эта кнопка.. как она посылает данные.. это просто POST или GET-форма?